# How does an already-made object be re-created (see example)

Tags: php, oop

I was looking at [OOP Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) and saw a code like this (simplified it a bit)

You can see this class and the output

```
class Test{}

$a  = new Test();
$b = new $a;

var_dump($b == $a); // true
```

What I don't understand is the `$b = new $a` but `$a` is already an object, so how/why does this work? If I do vardump `$a` the output is:

```
object(Test)#1 (0) {
}
```

So, how can that variable work with `new` keyword. I thought we could only use `new` with a class that is defined already, or with a string that points to a class ex:

```
$var = 'Test'; 
new $var; // ok
```

but in this case, `$var` is a string, not an another object.

Comment: i see it first time! very interesting!

Comment: PHP is smart enough to understand that since you are doing `new $a` and as $a is a object, not a string, it will use that object class name to instantiate the new object.

Comment: @RyanVincent Just curios, if the object are different they why do the have the same hash symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a shortcut for creating new object. Before PHP 5.3.0 you have to do this:

```
$class = get_class($instance);
$newInstance = new $class;
```

As of PHP 5.3.0 you can do the same thing with this:

```
$newInstance = new $instance;
```

Very useful, in my opinion, because it eliminates the need for a temporary variable.

To clarify, this creates new object. 
It is not cloning.
In other words, `__construct()` will be called instead of `__clone()`.